# Using ar_select_order from Python statsmodels 0.12.0 to determine optimal lag for AutoRegressive model

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, statsmodels

Using statsmodels 0.12.0 I am attempting to determine the optimal lag for a `statsmodels.tsa.ar_models.AutoReg` model. I am using US population data with monthly timesteps and passing in a maximum lag of 12 to the `statsmodels.tsa.ar_models.ar_select_order` object to evaluate.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg, ar_select_order    
df = pd.read_csv('Data\uspopulation.csv', index_col='DATE', parse_dates=True)
df.index.freq = 'MS'
train_data = df.iloc[:84]
test_data = df.iloc[84:]
modelp = ar_select_order(train_data['PopEst'], maxlag=12)
```

The code above returns a numpy array of `[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]`, which I am interpreting as "The optimal lag *p* is 12" as per this StackOverflow question: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048832/automatically-select-lags-for-autoregression-model-statsmodels). However, evaluating on some metrics (RMSE) I find that my AutoReg fitted models with `maxlag=12` are performing worse than lower order models. By trial and error I found that the optimal lag is 8. So I am having difficulty interpreting the resulting numpy array, i have been reading the resources on [statsmodels.com/ar_select_order](https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.12.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ar_select_order.html?highlight=ar_select_order) and [statsmodels.com/autoregressions](https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.12.0/examples/notebooks/generated/autoregressions.html?highlight=ar_select_order) but they have not made it clearer.

Does anyone here have any input? New to this python library and felling a bit lost.